# Finding source of a div "toolbar-top" on inhereted Magento 1.9 Project

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, toolbar, cpanel, category-navigation

I am working on a relatively complicated **Ecommerce store** on **Magento 1.9**. I need to add some very simple paragraph text above a `toolbar header` that floats in the `category navigation` section of the `store`.

Using Chrome's inspect element I can find that the toolbar is contained in a div called **"toolbar-top"** and I can find a lot of bootstrap files that control the styling. For what I need though, I need the source file of the div itself.

Most of the `phtml` files for the webpages seem to be in the directory for a custom theme "at-store" which has both "default" and "custom" directories that seem to be almost identical.

Does anybody have any thoughts on how I could go about tracking down the `div` containing this `toolbar`? Will be happy to provide more info once I get an idea of what kind of info would be relevant. Thank you very much!